# How to trigger PANIC in PostgreSQL 10

Tags: postgresql, fatal-error, error-logging

I'm using PostgreSQL 10 server version locally for educational purposes, and one of my tasks is to force a PANIC Error on this version just to test how is reported in the log files.

I've edited the `/etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf` and modified the following lines:

```
log_min_messages = PANIC
log_min_error_statement = PANIC
```

Following PostgreSQL's lastest documentation it specifies that:

> PANIC Reports an error that caused all database sessions to
>   abort.

I wanted to know if there was an easy way to trigger this kind of error and get it to be printed on the log files.

I searched a bit, but didn't find anything that could work easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting those two parameters to `PANIC` is not a good idea. Leave them at `ERROR` or `WARNING`, `PANIC` messages will be logged anyway.

There are many ways to provoke a panic. You could for example remove write permissions on the `pg_wal` directory or other important data structures. Then create some data modification activity (or call `pg_switch_wal` a couple of times).

Comment: I know it isn't a good idea, it's just an exercise. How exactly do I remove permissions on the `pg_wal`

Comment: Already tried and it didn't trigger a PANIC Error, just a warning.

`WARNING: terminating connection because crash of another server process`

Comment: Give `postgres` read and execute, but not write permissions on the directory. PostgreSQL will panic eventually. Speed it up by calling `SELECT pg_switch_wal()`.